# Mac Not Finding Homebrew Installed Python

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

So I've installed python via homebrow. When I do `brew info python` I get this:

```
python: stable 3.6.5 (bottled), devel 3.7.0rc1, HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1 (5,107 files, 103.0MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-06-18 at 10:15:49
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔, sphinx-doc ✘
Required: gdbm ✔, openssl ✔, readline ✔, sqlite ✔, xz ✔
Optional: tcl-tk ✘
==> Options
--with-tcl-tk
    Use Homebrew's Tk instead of macOS Tk (has optional Cocoa and threads support)
--devel
    Install development version 3.7.0rc1
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

If you need Homebrew's Python 2.7 run
  brew install python@2

Pip, setuptools, and wheel have been installed. To update them run
  pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
```

I'm ultimately trying to do `pip3 install numpy` but when I do that, I get this message:

```
-bash: pip3: command not found
```

`pip install numpy` seems to point to the Apple default 2.7 python version:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (1.14.5)
```

So the problem seems to be in my `.bash_profile` as `which python` gives `/usr/bin/python`.

Here's what that looks like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/bin:$PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/thammond/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

###########
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql\@9.6/9.6.6/bin:$PATH

###########

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

I confirmed that `/usr/local/` was listed at the top and also tried adding in `export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/bin:$PATH`

But it's still finding the wrong python. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

EDIT:

When I run `python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade` I see this:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

When I run `python3 -m ensurepip -vvv -U` I get this:

```
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
0 location(s) to search for versions of setuptools:
Skipping link /var/folders/7d/xvqc5yxs10n6206lytrbs9wm0000gn/T/tmpk6_9t6c2 (from -f); not a file
Skipping link file:///private/var/folders/7d/xvqc5yxs10n6206lytrbs9wm0000gn/T/tmpk6_9t6c2/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl; wrong project name (not setuptools)
Found link file:///private/var/folders/7d/xvqc5yxs10n6206lytrbs9wm0000gn/T/tmpk6_9t6c2/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl, version: 39.0.1
Local files found: /private/var/folders/7d/xvqc5yxs10n6206lytrbs9wm0000gn/T/tmpk6_9t6c2/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installed version (39.2.0) is most up-to-date (past versions: 39.0.1)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
0 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
Found link file:///private/var/folders/7d/xvqc5yxs10n6206lytrbs9wm0000gn/T/tmpk6_9t6c2/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl, version: 9.0.3
Skipping link file:///private/var/folders/7d/xvqc5yxs10n6206lytrbs9wm0000gn/T/tmpk6_9t6c2/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl; wrong project name (not pip)
Local files found: /private/var/folders/7d/xvqc5yxs10n6206lytrbs9wm0000gn/T/tmpk6_9t6c2/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installed version (10.0.1) is most up-to-date (past versions: 9.0.3)
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

When I look in `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/bin/` with finder I don't see a pip/pip3 file.

Comment: Have you tried `brew unlink python` and `brew link python --force`?

Comment: Run `brew info python` and read it carefully.

Comment: I have tried unlinking and force linking again. Updating full brew info python.

Comment: You are almost certainly going wrong if `/usr/local/Cellar/anything` occurs in your PATH. If you are using **homebrew**, your PATH should have `/usr/local/bin` near the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why it worked this time but just for kicks I decided to uninstall and reinstall python from homebrew again but this time it worked and pip3 installed correctly and works.

```
brew uninstall python3
brew install python3
```

now I can run `pip3 install numpy --user`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to invoke `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.5_1/bin/pip3` ? If it works, it means `pip` installation has been successfuly completed and your bashfile will be wrong. However,  the bashfile looks normal for me.

---

Did you confirm that there is `pip3` in `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.5_1/bin/`?
If it does not exist, `pip` is not installed in the first place.

It seems to have the same problem with [this page ("pip3 not installed with python 3.4.2 #33897")](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/33897).
The questioner of ["pip3 not installed with python 3.4.2 #33897"](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/33897) have finaly solved it by removing `/private/var/folders/hy/l_6wd1ps0nz835v4g41zhhtr0000gn/T/pip_build`.
It may be because of Brew had failed to complete `pip` installation.

First, to bootstrap the pip installer, hit `python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade` and `python -m ensurepip`.
If it won't work, try to hit `python3 -m ensurepip -vvv -U` and tell what do it say.